# How to create a va_list on GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, code-conversion

I'm trying to convert some code so that it compiles on gcc too (right now, it compiles only on MSVC).

The code I'm stuck at is in a pseudo-formatting function that accepts as input a format string and zero or more arguments (`const char *format, ...`). It will then process *some* of the placeholders consuming *some* of the arguments, and pass the rest to `vsprintf` along with a new va_list dynamically generated.

This is the actual code for generating the new `va_list`:

```
char *new_args = (char *) malloc(sum);
char *n = new_args;

for(int i = 0; i < nArgs; i++)
{
    int j   = order[i];
    int len = _getlen(types[j]);

    memcpy(n, args + cumulOffsets[j], len);
    n += len;
}

vsprintf(buffer, sFormat.c_str(), new_args);
```

In my defense, I didn't and would never write this code. In fact, I think it's one of the most hackiest things I've seen in my whole life.

However, this function is very complex, very old, and very important. It's also hasn't been modified in years (well, except now) so while I'd like to rewrite it from scratch I can't justify the time it would take plus the bugs it would introduce.

So, I need a way to do this same thing on GCC.. But there a `va_list` is not a `char *` so I'm getting:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type '__va_list_tag [1]'
```

Comment: consider using libffi ( http://sourceware.org/libffi/ )

Comment: I reckon this problem is insoluble. It's just not possible to dynamically construct a va_list in portable C/C++. Add to that the problem with __builtin_va_list not being defined in any header file, and the thing becomes doubly impossible.

Comment: Given more complete code for the function, it maybe possible to help you.  However, as TonyK said, there isn't a portable way to create a va_list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit lost.  Why do you need a ***new*** dynamically-generated *va_list*?  Why not just reuse the old one?

I believe *vsnprintf()* uses a current *va_list* object (if you can call it that).  So you are free to *va_start()*, use the arguments you want via *va_arg()*, then pass the remaining arguments via the *va_list* to *vsnprintf()*, and then call *va_end()*.

Am I missing something?  Why the deep copy?

And if you do need a deep copy, why not *va_start()* fresh, remove the arguments you want via *va_arg()*, and then pass the resulting *va_list* object to *vsnprintf()*.

(Each call to *va_arg* modifies the *va_list* object so that the next call returns the next argument.)

Alternatively, you could just use *va_copy()*.  (Though be sure to follow it with a corresponding *va_end()*.)

Addendum:  Also note that these va_ macros are based on C89 & C99 standards.  GNU g++ will support them.  Microsoft is somewhat more limited.

---

Following up on ***TonyK's*** comment:

What I said above works if you are pulling the first N items off the *va_list*.  If you are pulling items out of the middle, that's harder.

There is no portable way to ***construct*** a *va_list*.

However, you could pull apart the format string, use it to determine the object types (double,float,int,etc), and print each one out individually with it's own format string (a subsection of the original format string).  The multiple *snprintf()* calls will cause some overhead.  But if this routine isn't called too often, it should be viable.

You could also print out subsections of the original format string with a suitably crafted *va_list*.  In other words, the first *vsnprintf()* call prints elements 1..3, the second elements 5..7, the third 10..13, etc.  (As *vsnprintf()* will ignore extra elements on the *va_list* beyond what it needs.  You just need a series of corresponding format-string-fragments, and popping items off the *va_list* with *va_arg()* as needed for each *vsnprintf()* call.)

Comment: I think the OP wants to delete some of the arguments from an existing va_list before passing it to vsprintf. This looks difficult to me. gcc uses the built-in type __builtin_va_list for this, which is automatically pre-defined by the compiler -- it's not defined in any header files. So you would need to go to the source code of the compiler to see what it looks like, or look at some assembly language output. Neither of these alternatives is very inviting!

Comment: Thanks Tony.  I misunderstood.  I thought he was just popping items off the front, not from the middle.  Responded in-message as it got long...

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough context to figure out what you're trying to do here, but if you need to COPY a va_list, you may be able to use the C99 standard function `va_copy`, which gcc supports (but I have no idea if MS supports it).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, it isn't pretty:

```
union {
      char *pa;
      va_list al;
      } au;

....
au.pa = new_args;
vsprintf(buffer, sFormat.c_str(), au.al);
```

Using a union instead of a cast is ugly, but you can't cast if va_list is an array type.